# Вход через Гугл не работает после переподписания апк

Tags: android, firebase, apk, oauth

Я модифицировал ассеты приложения, но после переподписания перестал работать вход через гугл(Google Oauth). Видимо гугл сверяет подписи приложения(не уверен). Как это можно исправить?